# How to add 2 hours to variable in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add 2 hours to `$server_time` and call it `$hourPlusTwo`.  Everything i have tried ends up as either something like 7200 or some obscure date from 1969. How would you do it with what i have here, or rewritten a completely different way? Please understand i am new to php and programming in general. I am trying to understand how to do it, what would be better, and why it works.Thanks in advance.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
require_once('mysql_connection.php');
//analyse data by variable time period.
$hour_position = 45;
$htime = -30;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime($htime." day", $date);
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
$qry = "SELECT `last`,`server_time`,`vol` FROM `btce_btc_ticker` WHERE `server_time` > '$date' AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM `server_time`) = $hour_position ORDER BY `server_time` ASC";
$price_history_qry = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($price_history_qry)){

    $server_time = $result['server_time'];
    $server_time = date("m-d-Y (H:i)",strtotime($server_time));
    echo 'Server Hour ='.$server_time.'<br>';

    echo 'Two Hour ='.$hourPlusTwo.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: You want to add 2 hour to `$server_time` ?

Comment: yes. but keep the same format it is in.
Its' weird the date and time is stored in a different format than i want to display it. So my query is in one format, but i change it at the query results.

Comment: Which format you have and which format you need to have incremented by  2 hr ?

Comment: Maybe this pic will help explain my question.
http://screencast.com/t/z5tqWuIi7U

Comment: Got it, Writing answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You have your time format like this `date('Y-m-d (H:i)`

Whatever the time you got from the server you just need to speccify your format and add `+2 hour` from it.

The Change would be

```
$YourNewDate = date('Y-m-d (H:i)', strtotime('+2 hour'));
```

And the Result would be `2015-04-05 (23:05)` some value like this format.

**Update :**

As you want to do the increment from the time you have from db

```
<?php  
$result['server_time'] = '2014-04-18 19:56:00';
$server_time = $result['server_time'];
$hourPlusTwo = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $server_time);
echo date('Y-m-d (H:i)', strtotime('+2 hours', $hourPlusTwo->getTimestamp()));
?>
```

Comment: but that doesn't add it to the Referenced Server time, it's only referencing current time.
see  the results i am getting with that:
http://screencast.com/t/iymyJtvr

Comment: I want the output to be like this:
`Server Hour =03-06-2015 (12:45)
Two Hour =03-06-2015 (14:45)

Server Hour =03-06-2015 (13:45)
Two Hour =03-06-2015 (15:45)

Server Hour =03-06-2015 (14:45)
Two Hour =03-06-2015 (16:45)`

Comment: I have updated my answer, kindly check it, I have used the same naming that you used in your code :) and the output which is required by you Here is the screen [sreen](http://s15.postimg.org/s5fts0sy2/Screenshot_from_2015_04_06_00_49_47.jpg)

Comment: [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6e77832cc948cbc93f897ae51cbe39c765c3d89) is the code to test it online

Comment: That gives me a blank page. IF i remove the `getTimestamp()` It outputs 1969-12-31 (18:00)

Comment: You don't need to remove `getTimestamp()` I can show the demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/105e532399be2903823d00f9098033c15a392f84)

Comment: thats weird its' working on the demo site, but not on my site.

::EDIT:: This is working now! Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure, is there value for the `$result['server_time']` , can you echo that to test it